Failing to register Stimulus controller that import chart.js via npm
I'm developing a rails 7 application that uses the chart.js library via npm. When I include the following line
import Chart from "chart.js/auto"
in the stimulus controller, the browser's log gives the following message:
Failed to register controller: hello (controllers/hello_controller) TypeError: The specifier “chart.js/auto” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
I'd like to know why this error appears and how to fix it.
Steps to reproduce the error in a small rails application:

Versions:

> ruby -v
ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [x86_64-linux]
> rails -v
Rails 7.1.3.4


Create the rails application

> rails new example --css=bootstrap
> cd example
> rails g controller test index


app/views/test/index.html.erb

<h1>Test#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/test/index.html.erb</p>

<div data-controller="hello"></div>



app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.element.textContent = "Hello World!"
 }
}


Run the application:

>bin/dev

After opening a browser in the url http://localhost:3000/test/index, it works as expected giving no messages in the browsers log.

The error appears

6.1 Importing the chart.js library
> npm i chart.js
6.2 Importing library in the stimulus controller (app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.js)
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import Chart from "chart.js/auto" //just added this line 

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.element.textContent = "Hello World!"
 }
}

6.4. After reloading the page or restarting application, the following error message appears in the browser:
Failed to register controller: hello (controllers/hello_controller) TypeError: The specifier “chart.js/auto” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
What this message means? How to fix it?

is chart.js in your .node_modules directory? what's the exact path ? Is there really a path in .node_modules "chart.js/auto" ? seems unlikely. You need to find the path for the file you wish to import.

The node_modules directory is exists and is located at the root of the rails app and was automatically created with the rails new example --css=bootstrap command. The "chart.js/auto" directory exists and was creaetd with the ``npm i chart.js``` command.

You're using importmaps, you can't use npm this way, at least not without some extra configuration. You have to pin your packages in config/importmap.rb and then use configured imports:
$ bin/importmap pin chart.js/auto

Pinning "chart.js/auto" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:chart.js@4.4.3/auto/auto.js
Pinning "@kurkle/color" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@kurkle/color@0.3.2/dist/color.esm.js

import Chart from "chart.js/auto"

https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails#using-npm-packages-via-javascript-cdns

Note that importmap-rails v2 is currently broken, update your gemfile to use v1:
# Gemfile

gem "importmap-rails", "~> 1.0"


I tought I was using esbuild instead of importmaps since the app creation command included --css=bootstrap that created the node_modules directory.

I recreated the app without the --css=bootstrap and it found the chart.js lib.

I tried your sugestion in the original app (with --css=bootstrap) and got the same problem.

Just to mention: node_modules exists in the rails root AND includes "chart.js/auto" directory, It seems that it does not find it.

@user1644367 --css=bootstrap uses node only to compile css, importmaps for javascript. I tried my suggestion too (with --css=bootstrap), works as described. but you should just create your app with rails new example -c bootstrap -j esbuild

Thanks! With -j esbuild it works.
